# Forest, Figures and Landscape

Tags: floats, rotating, landscape, forest

I am currently having troubles with two figures I created, using the forest package. They are quiet large and not properly fit on the page, their rests are way beyond the page frames. I do not want to scale down their size, because they actually *are* quite large and I do not want the fonts to be too small. So I would like to rotate them by 90°. I tried doing this, with just rotating the figure as a whole, but then I cannot place both figures under each other, for each figure is set on a different page. So I used `pdflscape`. The figures properly come on the page now, even my header and page number are just fine. The only problem is now that the footnotes appear on the long side of the page, not on the short one. Does anyone know how to change it? That's my document preamble and the actual code for this page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{forest}%um Spielbäume zu zeichnen
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} %Mathematikumgebung
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[french,USenglish,UKenglish,ngerman]{babel}
% \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern} % ordentliche Schriften
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[babel,style=swiss,maxlevel=3,threshold=3]{csquotes}
    \newenvironment*{smallquote} %Alle \blockquotes sind mit einfachem Zeilenabstand und in kleinerer (\footnotesize) Größe.
    {\quote\singlespacing\smaller}
    {\endquote}
    \SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}

\usepackage{graphicx}
    \makeatletter 
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
    \makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}%für gute Copyright-Symbole
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{poetrytex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.75\textwidth}
    \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\footnotesize}
    \renewcommand{\beforeepigraphskip}{12pt}
    \renewcommand{\afterepigraphskip}{12pt}
\usepackage[]{acronym}


% An alternative to fancyhdr
\usepackage[markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[section]{section}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}



\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt} % damit wird der Abstand vor und nach Kapiteln und (Sub-)Sections geregelt
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing{\invisiblesection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{14pt}{\Large}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\thesection}{14pt}{\large}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
\sectionmark{#1}}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\usepackage{tocloft} %für Schriftgröße etc. des Inhaltsverzeichnis und des Abbildungsverzeichnis
    \renewcommand\cftchapfont{\large}
    \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{24pt}
    \renewcommand\cftaftertoctitleskip{12pt}
    \renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{24pt}
    \renewcommand\cftafterloftitleskip{12pt}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
    \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}


\usepackage{footmisc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter %sorgt dafür, dass die Fußnoten am linken Rand nicht überstehen, sondern mit dem Horizontalstrich gemeinsam schließen.
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent\normalfont\@thefnmark~#1
}
\makeatother

% \textheight=\vfill% just for the example, wofür?
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ }

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@makefntext}{%
    \let\org@makefntext\@makefntext
    \renewcommand*{\@makefntext}{%
        \addtolength{\hsize}{-1cm}%
        \org@makefntext
    }%
}
\makeatother
\flushbottom%macht die Fußnoten gleichmäßig mit einem cm Abstand zum Haupttext.

\newenvironment{literatur}{%
    \parskip6pt \parindent0pt
    \def\lititem{\hangindent=0.5cm \hangafter1}}{%
    \par\ignorespaces} %damit wird der hängende Einzug für das Literaturverzeichnis ermöglicht.



\usepackage{rotating}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
                            \begin{figure}[h]
                                \centering
                                    \centering  
                                    \scalebox{0.8}{
                                        \begin{forest}
                                    [\enquote{Malen}
                                    [gegenständlich
                                    [funktional
                                    [Pläne]
                                    [Phantomskizzen]
                                    [Protkolle]
                                    [\ldots]
                                    ]
                                    [ästhetisch
                                    [abbildend]
                                    [imaginativ
                                    [real]
                                    [phantastisch]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    [abstrakt
                                    [funktional
                                    [therapeutisch]
                                    [\ldots]
                                    ]
                                    [ästhetisch
                                    [konstruiert
                                    [futiristisch]
                                    [monochrom]
                                    [skriptural]
                                    ]
                                    [automatisch
                                    [informell]
                                    [tachistisch]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                    ]
                                        \end{forest}}
                                        \caption[Funktionalität und Ästhetizität gemalter Zeichen]{Funktionalität und Ästhetizität gemalter Zeichen.\footnotemark}
                                        \label{fig:mal_zeichen}
                                \end{figure}
                                \footnotetext{Eigene darstellung nach \textit{ebd}., S.~129.}
                                \begin{figure}[h]   
                                    \centering
                                        \begin{forest}
                                    [Schreiben
                                        [mechanisch
                                            [Inhalt erhaltend (gesetzt)]
                                            [Form und Inhalt erhaltend (Faksimile)]
                                        ]
                                        [manuell
                                            [Druckschrift (standardisiert)]
                                            [Kursivschrift (individuell)]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                        \end{forest}
                                        \caption[Funktionalität und Ästhetizität geschriebener Zeichen]{Funktionalität und Ästhetizität geschriebener Zeichen.\footnotemark}
                                        \label{fig:schrift_zeichen}
                                            \end{figure}
                                    \footnotetext{Eigene Darstellung nach \textit{ebd}., S.~143.}           
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nothing like minimal! Why do you have such an absurd number of irrelevant packages?

Comment: I don't really know what you want to do. Of course, it is better to use a smaller font for the first tree rather than scaling it. That much is obvious. But the footnotes seem to be positioned correctly at the bottom of the page, so that they are orientated to be read when the page is rotated to display the trees correctly. I assume you don't want the footnotes to run orthogonally to the trees which reference them, but then I can't think what other possibilities might be wanted. That said, I'd include the information in the captions if it is required.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use

```
for tree={font=\footnotesize}
```

for the first tree rather than scaling it. However, that is well known, presumably obvious.

The footnotes appear as I'd expect and want them to they are orientated with the trees.

That said, I would rethink the way the first tree is drawn to try to avoid reducing the font size. For example, you might stagger the nodes.

[image: fit tree by staggering nodes]

[You would need to adjust the placement of the footnotes in this case, so those for the second tree end up on the right page.]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm,headheight=14.5pt,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{forest}
        for tree={
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          where={iseven(n())}{}{
            replace by={[, shape=coordinate, append]}
          }
        },
        before packing={
          forked edges,
        }
        [\enquote{Malen}
          [gegenständlich
            [funktional
              [Pläne]
              [Phantomskizzen]
              [Protkolle]
              [\ldots]
            ]
            [ästhetisch
              [abbildend]
              [imaginativ
                [real]
                [phantastisch]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [abstrakt
            [funktional
              [therapeutisch]
              [\ldots]
            ]
            [ästhetisch
              [konstruiert
                [futiristisch]
                [monochrom]
                [skriptural]
              ]
              [automatisch
                [informell]
                [tachistisch]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      \end{forest}
    \caption[Funktionalität und Ästhetizität gemalter Zeichen]{Funktionalität und Ästhetizität gemalter Zeichen.\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:mal_zeichen}
  \end{figure}
  \footnotetext{Eigene darstellung nach \textit{ebd}., S.~129.}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
      [Schreiben
      [mechanisch
      [Inhalt erhaltend (gesetzt)]
      [Form und Inhalt erhaltend (Faksimile)]
      ]
      [manuell
      [Druckschrift (standardisiert)]
      [Kursivschrift (individuell)]
      ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption[Funktionalität und Ästhetizität geschriebener Zeichen]{Funktionalität und Ästhetizität geschriebener Zeichen.\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:schrift_zeichen}
  \end{figure}
  \footnotetext{Eigene Darstellung nach \textit{ebd}., S.~143.}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```